# Confusing prepositions in a sentence

Tags: prepositions

What will be the prepositions in the following sentence:

"The authority was preparing narrow, targeted XY (any organization) sanctions __ Steven's academy and could roll __ the punitive measures __ the year-end," said the official who spoke on condition __ anonymity.

MY ASSUMPTIOON:
  for , at, down , of.

Comment: Why do you think those are right?  What research have you done on these prepositions?

Comment: 3 of 4 are incorrect, but we are not here to do your homework for you. If this is from a practice quiz for a test that you are planning to take, this rate of errors suggests it would be best for you to take another half-year or year of studying English before you attempt to take this test (especially if it costs money to take it). A good strategy would be to google words like "sanctions" and "punitive measures" and read articles to see how these words are used in context, and write down phrases in which they come up.

Comment: For is correct. Look up "roll out." We say "by the year-end." Of is correct. So I say two of four are incorrect. And you spelled "assumption" wrong, but I suspect that is an accident. :)  Prepositions are confusing in most languages, so you just have to learn them.

Comment: @BobRodes in this context, "against" is more appropriate than "for". Sanctions "for" X imply that X is that specific wrongdoing _for_ which sanctions were imposed. "Steven's academy" is not a wrongdoing. Aaaaand, we have half-answered the OP's question (should we have?)

Comment: ah, yes, BobRodes answered the whole question...

Comment: @tenebris2020 Against is more precise, it is true, but I'd say for is acceptable. And I thought about whether to answer the question as well. The fact that he/she got two (or 1.5, if you will) right suggests that he/she's already put some effort into it, and they can be difficult to look up. But yeah, maybe I should have given him/her some things to read instead.

Comment: Well, yes, accumptioons can be problematical. against, out, at, of. You only got one right. Like tenebris said, you need to study more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several choices:

For targetting sanctions, you might use

> sanctions **at** Steven's academy
>   sanctions **for** Steven's academy

for delivering something:

> roll **out**

to give a time frame:

> **before** the year-end
>   **by** the year-end
>   **at** the year-end

usually "***the***" would not be included.

And the final one is an idiom:

> on condition **of** anonymity